# Electronjs how to detect if monitor/screen is off

Tags: electron

How can we detect if monitor is off. Electron provides [electron.screen](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/screen) API where we can retrieve all displays `electron.screen.getAllDisplays()` but information provided here does not container about monitors' power status:

```
[{
    id: 2528732444,
    bounds: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    workArea: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1040 },
    accelerometerSupport: 'unknown',
    monochrome: false,
    colorDepth: 24,
    colorSpace: '{primaries:BT709, transfer:IEC61966_2_1, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}',
    depthPerComponent: 8,
    size: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    workAreaSize: { width: 1920, height: 1040 },
    scaleFactor: 1,
    rotation: 0,
    internal: false,
    touchSupport: 'unknown'
  },
...
]
```

If display is not plugged in to the PC then won't list it. However, if monitor is plugged in to PC and turned off it lists it in `electron.screen.getAllDisplays()` and but does not provide its status.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, something like DVI or HDMI will still report a screen as being connected even if the display is off (which is why it shows up in getAllDisplays()).

The only option I could think of is would be to run a shell script that accesses the
Win32 API, but that would no longer be based on Electron.

You would use the [Power Setting GUIDs of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/power-setting-guids?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE

```
6FE69556-704A-47A0-8F24-C28D936FDA47

The current monitor's display state has changed.

Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008: This notification is available starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

The Data member is a DWORD with one of the following values.

0x0 - The display is off.

0x1 - The display is on.

0x2 - The display is dimmed.
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, can you share a shell command to pull monitor power status, I can't find it on google.

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you there as personally I'd write a C# app to handle it, not exactly sure how Electron does it.

My suggestion is that if this is not app critical, avoid it, and if it is, rather move to a more "native" language. Trying to access windows specific API's should not really be done in an electron app, the idea is that it's platform agnostic. You can, but just not recommended.

That said, for your use-case, I'd probably write a standalone C# app and then have it post to an open port on the electron app that something's changed, otherwise you can try Powershell.